# In Markdown, what is the best way to link to a fragment of a page, i.e. #some_id?

Tags: html, markdown

I'm trying to figure out how to reference another area of a page with Markdown. I can get it working if I add a

```
<div id="mylink" />
```

and for the link do:

```
[My link](#mylink)
```

But my guess is that there's some other way to do an in-page link in Markdown that doesn't involve the straight up `div` tag.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've always done them just the way you've done here.

Comment: `<div/>` can upset the formatter for the rest of the page. Use `<a id="ident"/>`. See my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-reference (named anchor) in markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319754/cross-reference-named-anchor-in-markdown)

Comment: Consider using MultiMarkdown instead. It provides the `[anchor][]` syntax to do this. https://github.com/fletcher/MultiMarkdown/wiki/MultiMarkdown-Syntax-Guide#automatic-cross-references

Answer (score 187):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695439/how-do-you-create-link-to-a-named-anchor-in-multimarkdown/7015050#7015050).

In summary make a destination with

```
<a name="sometext"></a>
```

inserted anywhere in your markdown markup (for example in a header:

```
## heading<a name="headin"></a>
```

and link to it using the markdown linkage:

```
[This is the link text](#headin)
```

or

```
[some text](#sometext)
```

Don't use `<div>` -- this will mess up the layout for many renderers.

(I have changed `id=` to `name=` above. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7335259/57171) for the tedious explanation.)

Comment: +1, thanks. It's sad it doesn't do this automatically. Very wet IMHO.

Comment: It's ugly when you have to read it in a text editor, but, it _does_ work. Not sure why this isn't the accepted answer.

Comment: Defining old style anchors `<a name="..." />` is [*obsolete but conforming*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete-but-conforming-features) in later HTML specifications.
If `<div>` might be rendered as a disrupting block (maybe if for undisclosed reasons the CSS is giving a size) maybe `<span>` (an inline element) might do the trick?

Comment: To reuse the tag without appending `(#sometext)` each time, we can use the markdown syntax by appending the link list at the end of the markdown file, i.e. `[some text]:#sometext`, then we can directly use `[some text]` to create the link. Hope this can help future readers.

Answer (score 36):

I guess this depends on what you're using to generate html from your markdown. I noticed, that jekyll (it's used by gihub.io pages by default) automatically adds the id="" attribute to headings in the html it generates.

For example if you're markdown is

```
My header
---------
```

The resulting html will look like this:

```
<h2 id="my-header">My header</h2>
```

So you can link to it simply by `[My link](#my-header)`

Comment: This is the best and clean answer. Markdown is really cool. it really helps to do fast blogging. ^_^

Comment: I can confirm that this works for ruby gems hosted at rubygems.org as well. All the documentation from headers in the .md file will have these id entries. I needed to find out because I had to document ruby-gtk content, and allow quick jumping to the upstream classes (which are written in C, in GTK or GTK+).

Comment: I see that pandoc, Markdown Preview Enhanced for vscode and vscode native preview will also add this id attribute. However this is extension behavior and is not in CommonMark specification. CommonMark implementations like [cmark](https://github.com/commonmark/cmark) won't generate the id attribute.

Answer (score 18):

With the [PHP version of Markdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/), you can also link headers to fragment identifiers within the page using a syntax like either of the following, as documented [here](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/#header-id)

```
Header 1            {#header1}
========

## Header 2 ##      {#header2}
```

and then

```
[Link back to header 1](#header1)
[Link back to header 2](#header2)
```

Unfortunately this syntax is currently only supported for headers, but at least it could be useful for building a table of contents.

Answer (score 4):

The destination anchor for a link in an HTML page may be any element with an `id` attribute.  See [Links](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html) on the W3C site.  Here's a quote from the relevant section:

> Destination anchors in HTML documents
>   may be specified either by the A
>   element (naming it with the name
>   attribute), or by any other element
>   (naming with the id attribute).

Markdown treats HTML as HTML (see [Inline HTML](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html)), so you can create your fragment identifiers from any element you like.  If, for example, you want to link to a paragraph, just wrap the paragraph in a paragraph tag, and include an id:

```
<p id="mylink">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
```

Then use your standard Markdown `[My link](#mylink)` to create a link to fragment anchor.  This will help to keep your HTML clean, as there's no need for extra markup.

Comment: In my experience using the `<p>` tag in Markdown can strip the CSS of a regular paragraph. I'd say use with caution, I'm new to Markdown but it has some quirks.

Comment: @user691859 I'm not sure what you mean by "using the `<p>` tag in Markdown can strip the CSS of a regular paragraph". Markdown wraps paragraphs in `<p>` tags, and ignores those that already have `<p>` tags. I can't see how this would affect CSS...

Comment: The behavior is erratic for me. On tumblr, using <p> can (not always) strip all the behavior besides the specific behavior I specified. I do not know why. <div> ALWAYS does the same though.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone use Visual Studio Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2015, it really does not like embedded `<a>` or `<div>` elements, at least in headers. It also doesn't like emoji in headers either:

```
###  Configuration 

Lorem ipsum problem fixem.
```

Gets translated to:

```
<h3 id="-configuration-"> Configuration </h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum problem fixem.</p>
```

And so links should either use that `id` (which breaks [this](https://github.com/madskristensen/MarkdownEditor) and other preview extensions in Visual Studio), or remove the emoji:

```
Here's [how to setup](#-configuration-) // Configuration 
Here's [how to setup](#configuration) //Configuration
```

Where the latter version works both online in TFS *and* in the markdown preview of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

In Pandoc Markdown you can set anchors on arbitrary spans inside a paragraph using syntax `[span]{#anchor}`, e.g.:

```markdown
Paragraph, containing [arbitrary text]{#mylink}.
```

And then reference it as usual: `[My link](#mylink)`.

If you want to reference a whole paragraph then the most straightforward way is to add an *empty* span right in the beginning of the paragraph:

```markdown
[]{#mylink}
Paragraph text.
```