# adding an anchor in octopress post

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, octopress

I am using Octopress and I know that in order to add an image in my post, instead of writing:

```
<img src="src" alt="alt" class="class" />
```

I can write:

```
{% img class src alt %}
```

And, instead if writing:

```
<a href="href">text</a>
```

I can write:

```
[text](href)
```

But how can I write:

```
<a href="href" target="target">text</a>
```

?

If this is not possible and the only solution is to write the html tag, where and how can I add ruby code translate this for example: `[text](href target)` to this: `<a href="href" target="target">text</a>`?

In addition, where can I find a list of all those html octopress shortcuts?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7335259/1019358

Comment: @seliopou: Didn't understand how this answer can help me add the target property.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually controlled by the Markdown engine used to process the text rather than any Octopress code. Depending on the engine you are using, you can write

```
[text](href){: target="target" }
```

This is called an "inline attribute list", and is an extension to the Markdown syntax. It is supported by [Maruku](http://maruku.rubyforge.org/proposal.html), as well as [Kramdown](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/syntax.html#inline-attribute-lists).

(Note that Maruku is Jekyll's default Markdown engine, so this syntax is supported if you haven't touched this aspect of the configuration.)

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work and just append {: target="_blank" } after the anchor text. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the Markdown Syntax:

```
[text](#target)
```

#### For `<a href="href" target="target">text</a>`

```
[text](href){: target="target" }
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work and just append {: target="_blank" } after the anchor text. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The `{% img class src alt %}` is a octopress tag, see the [plugin docs](http://octopress.org/docs/) for more tags.

The `[text](href)` follow the [markdown sintax](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet), and does not let you add classes, attributes, or ids to elements.

So to workaround the target problem use the [snipet](https://gist.github.com/wagnerpinheiro/9392929) below in your custom header layout, and added the `#_blank` anchor at the end of the url, to open in a new window.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function addBlankTargetForLinks () {
    $('a[href^="http"],a[href*="#_blank"]').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
    });
}

$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
    addBlankTargetForLinks();
});
</script>
```