# Create an inline link to a definition-list item in Markdown

Tags: markdown, sublimetext3

I would like to be able to generate hyperlinks in text and code to the definition list at the end of the document.

This syntax does NOT work:

Definition list (at end of document)

```
[1]: Donation Date
: The date on which the organ was recovered from the donor.

~~~
TRANSPLANT.SURGERY_DATE
when TRANSPLANT.TYPE_ID = DONOR [1]
~~~
```

Link in text

```
[Donation Date][1] should be after the start of this year.
```

Link in code block

```
`[Donation Date][1] >= 01/01/2016`
```

The Markdown is rendered as `[1]: Donation Date` and `[Donation Date][1]` respectively.

Is it possible to create a link to a definition list?

Using Sublime Text 3 and [Markdown Preview](http://markdownlivepreview.com/) package to build the HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-reference (named anchor) in markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319754/cross-reference-named-anchor-in-markdown)