# Markdown link within document to heading with a period

Tags: markdown

I have a Markdown document with a header in it like:

```
## my-script.sh
```

I want to create a named anchor as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5319754/3787051) Stack Overflow question. So I hoped this would work:

```
[my-script.sh](#my-script-sh)
```

It doesn't though. Various examples of what I have tried are available at Github [here](https://github.com/alexharv074/bash-test/commit/07076b514dd6f72c43f8708d9b283b3c86bbefe5) [here](https://github.com/alexharv074/bash-test/tree/0e6519a5c5fc9d638546ed872741b870f886cfcd) [here](https://github.com/alexharv074/bash-test/tree/c903d5ef87d0277f8800559e4efc0436c68ae573) [here](https://github.com/alexharv074/bash-test/tree/6f950eb8282b4864e98005d2f9bc4dc7a0564596) [here](https://github.com/alexharv074/bash-test/tree/38f414a489c463081196b3a9aff5fbe4c5f03760).

How can I make this work (without removing the dot from the header)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect :

- Only one pad is referenced instead of two.
- the `.sh` takes it as a file

### An solution

Try you the following :

```
[my-script.sh](##`my-script.sh`)

## `my-script.sh`
```

What we have done is to disambiguate what is obtained as a file, converting it into a name when putting it in quotation marks.

### Updated <sub>22012019110907</sub>

Before an interesting investigation about why the previously proposed did not work, I have achieved a (temporary) solution that works.

The solution is to **obtain the link through the readme symbol**:

[image: Adding link]

Copy the link and generate it in our link:

```
[test.sh](https://github.com/<nameuser>/<namerepo>/<branch>/test#testsh)

## `test.sh`
```

For example :

```
[test.sh](https://github.com/user/myrepo/tree/test#testsh)

## `test.sh`
```

#### Try me

[**This**](https://gist.github.com/nicolasalarconrapela/3aee67d541271b8775bc1a50f1032c00) or in code snippet :

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/nicolasalarconrapela/3aee67d541271b8775bc1a50f1032c00.js"></script>
```

Comment: @AlexHarvey Where are you implementing this?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by it worked in Visual Code- do you mean it displays properly in a particular version of Markdown?

Comment: I updated the question with links to 4 versions of that that I tried and code you can look at at Github.

Comment: @AlexHarvey I review

Answer (score 6):

As far as Github Flavoured Markdown is concerned, which is shown in the update by Nicolás Alarcón R. above, if you have a header:

```
## my-script.sh
```

The syntax for creating an inline link to it is:

```
[my-script.sh](#my-scriptsh)
```

Comment: What other characters are off limits for the id tags?