# Gitlab, in markdown, how can I use anchors other than headers?

Tags: visual-studio-code, hyperlink, gitlab, markdown

I would like to use links in markdown that points to an element in a list or a table (or text) and not specially a header.

The only solution I found for markdown is to use HTML anchors :

```
This is a list of actions:
- <a id="action-one">action one</a>`: blablanla
- <a id="action-two">action two</a>`: patata

Later, in text, [action one](#action-one) is mandatory...
```

This works well in VScode (for example) but not in Gitlab.

FYI:

- Using `name` instead of `id` [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7335259/1451467) would not work for vscode.
- [In the official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#links), there's only mention of `header` anchors.

Any idea or solution is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to say there isn't one. VSCode is interpreting the HTML, so it works, but on GitLab, HTML is not generally supported in descriptions/comments.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround for the limitations of [bmaupin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77411578/11370158), which is to add an empty link to the `<a>` tag with the `id` and `name`:

```html
<a id="link-ref" name="link-ref"></a>
<a href="#link-ref"></a>
```

In particular, I used this for headings like this:

```md
## 2.3 ▸ some section <a id="2.3" name="2.3"></a><a href="#2.3"></a>
```

which renders the heading's text to "2.3 ▸ some section"

The link is needed because gitlab's markdown engine is too smart for our own good and "guesses" that the `<a>` tag is not needed if there's no link pointing to it.

Answer (score 1):

GitLab doesn't allow user-set HTML ID attributes in Markdown. The [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#inline-html) does go into more detail about HTML sanitization.

I've only found two workarounds:

- If you only care about anchors within the same page, use `id` and `name`, e.g.

  ```html
  <a id="action-one" name="action-one">action one</a>
  ```

  Alternatively, if you don't want the anchor text to be underlined, you can leave it outside of the `a` tags, e.g.

  ```html
  <a id="action-one" name="action-one"></a>action one
  ```

  - In VS Code and in GitLab, this seems to work well for anchors in the same page
  - For anchor links to other pages, both VS Code and GitLab will show the other page but not go to the anchor (although this may vary by browser)
  - In particular, GitLab will strip out the `id` tag, e.g.

    ```html
    <a name="action-one">action one</a>
    ```

- If you must show an anchor in a different page, the only solution I've found is to use [Markdown headings](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#headers), e.g .

  ```markdown
  #### Action one
  ```

  These work great in VS Code as well as GitLab. GitLab will convert the Markdown to something like this:

  ```html
  <h4><a aria-hidden="true" href="#action-one" class="anchor" id="user-content-action-one"></a>Action one</h4>
  ```

  While this isn't ideal, one nice thing is that headings work in lists, and you can use a smaller heading (e.g. h5 or even h6) to make them less conspicuous. Using the example from the question, this could look like:

  ```markdown
  This is a list of actions:

  - ##### action one: blablanla
  - ##### action two: patata
  ```

Comment: Thank you, @bmaupin, for your time and response. As I noted in my question, using heading tags was not an option; the solution needs to point to a list. At the time of my original post in 2020, I tried your suggested solution of using both the id and name attributes, but it did not work. Perhaps it will now. I will test it and confirm if the solution works on both GitLab and VSCode. Thank you once again.