# RMarkdown Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm looking to add a Bootstrap navigation bar (as shown here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) to an R Markdown template I am creating.

From reading around, I've seen how you can add HTML elements from another file and call them within R Markdown.

But, is there anyway to include the HTML code inside of the markdown file, that way that navigation bar still gets added, but I only have a single page needed to show the results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This requires a `.yml`(yaml) file to compliment our Rmarkdown file.

our almost empty Rmarkdown file titled `index.Rmd`...

```
---
title: "navbar for stackoverflow"
---
```

Now we just add code to our `.yml` file for our navbar. Rmarkdown looks inside  it's root directory for a `_site.yml` file for rendering instructions per the [blogdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/), which is the same author as your reference.

inside our `_site.yml` file inside the same directory as our `index.Rmd` file...

```
name: "Rmarkdown with navbar"                                
output_dir: "."
navbar:
  title: "Rmarkdown with navbar"                            
  type: inverse
  right:
    - text: "Contact me"
      icon: fa-envelope-o
      href: https://www.stackoverflow.com                  
    - text: "GitHub"
      icon: fa-github
      href: https://www.stackoverflow.com  
    - text: "Stackoverflow"
      icon: fa-stack-overflow
      href: https://www.stackoverflow.com  
    - text: "Youtube"
      icon: fa-youtube
      href: https://www.stackoverflow.com  
    - text: "Instagram"
      icon: fa-instagram
      href: https://www.stackoverflow.com  
    - text: "Twitter"
      icon: fa-twitter
      href: https://www.stackoverflow.com  
output:
  html_document:
    theme: spacelab
    highlight: textmate
```

Which renders the below output.

[image]

The `theme` argument in the yaml file IS one of the select few bootstrap options Rmarkdown comes installed with.

Comment: How can I add the scroll to a section animations when clicking on a button?

Comment: I think that would be called “anchors” so look up “rmarkdown anchors”  or [here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319754/cross-reference-named-anchor-in-markdown) for a similar SO question

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out! The best solution I have found for this is to use RHTML to create the markdown file:

https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-hardcore.html

From there, you can use HTML to create the backbone of your document, and wrap your R code like so:

```
<!--begin.rcode
df <- data.frarme(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)
df
end.rcode-->
```

This definitely will require more work on my end, but it gives me exactly what I've been looking for.