# Linking to a section in another markdown file

Tags: azure-devops, markdown

I'm trying to link to a section in another markdown file is this possible?

So for example, given I have the following `readme.md` file:

```markdown
[Sub Heading Title](Intro.md#subheadingTitle)
```

When I link to the file `Intro.md` I have this:

```markdown
# HeadingTitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


## SubheadingTitle 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat.
```

Then I expect to be navigated to the specified section called `Sub Heading Title`.

My problem is that when I click on the `Sub Heading Title` link it doesn't navigate to the sub heading specified and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Which tool are you using? Adding IDs to headers is not an official part of Markdown and not all tools do it. Of those that do, each does it slightly differently. For example, some will change capitalization in specific ways, others in different ways, and others won't change capitalization at all.

Comment: Also, there are a number of *almost* duplicates to this question. While technically different, I suspect you will find many helpful answers: [How to link to part of the same document in Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2822089/866026) (specific to MultiMarkdown and the same document); [Cross-reference (named anchor) in markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5319754/866026) (does not mention "another document" although the answers apply to both); [Should I make HTML Anchors with 'name' or 'id'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/484719/866026) (clearly a different, albeit related question).

Comment: The markdown files is for azure devops.

Comment: I'm not personally familiar with azure devops and don't know what system they use for Markdown. However, I added the appropriate tag to your question. Perhaps someone familiar with that system will be able to help.

Comment: @nless Where are your markdown files? Are they in the same page? Can you share a screenshot about the location of your markdown files?

Comment: I'll check the microsoft documentation for answers. For anyone else's benefit that is finding problems check out this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/about-readme-wiki?view=azure-devops

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got my answer from here. I'll check the Microsoft documentation for answers. For anyone else's benefit that is finding problems check out this link learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/…

Comment: This answer contains only a link and does not actually provide an answer to the question.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#anchor-links -- This is the section that answers the question. Basically, anchor IDs are assigned to all headings, spaces are replaced by dashes (-) and all lowercase.