# How to link to a named anchor in Multimarkdown?

Tags: markdown, multimarkdown

I have come across a number of mentions of MultiMarkdown's support for internal links / named anchors but I am unable to find a single example of how to actually do it.

So, what is the syntax for denoting the named anchor, and what is the syntax for linking to it the same as linking to any other URLs (only using #foo instead of `http://....`)?

Comment: If you're doing this to create a table of contents I'd recommend [doctoc](https://github.com/thlorenz/doctoc) to automate this (requires [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)). Doctoc generates the markdown code so it will provide an example of how to link to headings throughout the document too (as described in @user1789493's answer).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-reference (named anchor) in markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319754/cross-reference-named-anchor-in-markdown)

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Taken from the [Multimarkdown Users Guide](http://fletcher.github.com/peg-multimarkdown/index#cross-references) (thanks to @MultiMarkdown on Twitter for pointing it out)

`[Some Text][]`will link to a header named “Some Text”
e.g.

```
### Some Text ###
```

An optional label of your choosing to help disambiguate cases where multiple headers have the same title:

```
### Overview [MultiMarkdownOverview] ##
```

> This allows you to use [MultiMarkdownOverview] to refer to this section specifically, and not another section named Overview. This works with atx- or settext-style headers.
>
> If you have already defined an anchor using the same id that is used by a header, then the defined anchor takes precedence.
>
> In addition to headers within the document, you can provide labels for images and tables which can then be used for cross-references as well.

Comment: FWIW, it doesn't work with emacs' markdown-mode as of 23.4.1.

Comment: Markdown does not support footnotes. As such it won't work in most "Markdown" modes. MultiMarkdown, however supports a number of extensions that make life easier for writers.

Comment: Github does not seem to support labels in headers?

Comment: This does not work (at least on codepen.io) when there is ':' in the header.

Comment: that link is the documentation by the guy who wrote MultiMarkdown. Not sure what you're doing in codepen.io but i'm confident the docs are accurate. Keep in mind *MULTI*Markdown NOT Markdown.

Answer (score 849):

In standard Markdown, place an anchor `<a name="abcd"></a>` where you want to link to and refer to it on the same page by `[link text](#abcd)`.

(This uses `name=` and not `id=`, for reasons explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7335259/57171).)

Remote references can use `[link text](http://...#abcd)` of course.

This works like a dream, provided you have control over the source and target texts. The anchor can even appear in a heading, thus:

```
### <a name="head1234"></a>A Heading in this SO entry!
```

produces:

#### A Heading in this SO entry!

and we can even link to it so:

```
and we can even [link](#head1234) to it so:
```

(On SO, the link doesn't work because the anchor is stripped.)

Comment: @jj1bdx I do now -- the `<a id="id"></a>` form is best. See [this SO question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319754/cross-reference-named-anchor-in-markdown/7335259#7335259).

Comment: Nice addition Steve. I'd mark it as the answer except the question was about MultiMarkdown. Obviously people's votes are indicating that this was a helpful addition though. So, thanks.

Comment: Fyi: Github markdown expects you to use name= instead of id, it seems.

Comment: @Dieter: `name=` was deprecated in XHTML, but now I find that `id=` has a side-effect in HTML5, so I am reverting to `name=` in this answer.

Comment: Is there any way to get this to work on StackOverflow?

Comment: Works on github-flavored-markdown (the ruby gem renders it as expected)

Comment: This only works for the first time I click on the link. If I click on the link, it scrolls down and changes the URL. If I manually scroll up and click on the link again, it does not navigate back to the link. Anyone else experience this?

Comment: Didn't work for me in Pandoc extended markdown, might work elsewhere.

Comment: It looks to be supported by BitBucket with name attribute (did not try the id attribute).

Comment: That's a shame that this is not possible on SO :( the `id="foo"` part of any HMTL element is always stripped

Comment: All my id="xx" hashtags has been broken on https://github.com. Switch to name="" - works perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 803):

If you have headers in the markdown files, you can directly link them in the file.

Markdown Header:

```markdown
## The Header
```

this will generate an implicit id `#the-header` (replace internal spaces with hyphens and make lowercase).

To navigate to this id, you can create the link like this:

```markdown
[Link to Header](#the-header)
```

This is equivalent to:

```html
<a href="#the-header">Link to Header</a>
```

Please note the reference's name is a lower-case `#header`.

Comment: BitBucket seems to prefix the anchor id with "markdown-header-". So if your header is `## This Header ##`, the link would be `[To This Header](#markdown-header-this-header)`. If you aren't sure what the id of your header is, use a page inspector to see the HTML values.

Comment: Didn't work for me in Pandoc extended markdown, might work elsewhere.

Comment: @SaurabhM this will ONLY work IF your markdown to html converter DOES NOT adhere to the standard. The standard doesn't create anchor tags. Now, many don't adhere, but you should NOT _expect_ this to work anywhere.

Comment: Why oh why did we have to *standardize* in something as *standard-less* and half-baked as Markdown. Can't wait for AsciiDoc to take the lead.

Comment: What if the header is "# The - Header"

Comment: What do you do if the header has a / in it?

Comment: GitHub adds user-content before the name of the header: `[Link](user-content-the-header)`

Comment: GitHub will also make `# 5.4` into `user-content-54` and lose the `.`

Comment: Also works to add a "%20" where the blank space is supposed to be, but I guess a hyphen is much more elegant

Comment: It does not seems to be supported in Bitbucket. I use the anchor `<a name="link">` instead.

Comment: If there are some symbols in the string such as /, #, + and others simply omit them; e.g. `## The Header++` has the same linking of the simple `##The Header` . If you have multiple headers that reduce to the same link, the headers following the first should be numbered. For example if you have first `#The Header` and then `#The Header++` the first link will be `[Link to Header](#the-header)`, while the second `[Link to second Header](#the-header-1)`

Comment: I want this answer to be the one marked correct, because it is the most useful and best answer IMHO.

Comment: @hmijail Wow, thanks for mentioning Asciidoc! I hadn't heard of it, but it looks _so_ much better, and renaming my `README.md` to `README.adoc` makes it show up properly on GitHub! I wonder why GitHub doesn't make it the default for new projects. (I asked Google, and its AI came up with what seems a strange and incorrect answer to me.)

Answer (score 142):

I tested *Github Flavored Markdown* for a while and can summarize with four rules:

1. punctuation marks will be dropped
2. leading white spaces will be dropped
3. upper case will be converted to lower
4. spaces between letters will be converted to `-`

For example, if your section is named this:

```
## 1.1 Hello World
```

Create a link to it this way:

```
[Link](#11-hello-world)
```

Comment: What if there are hyphens in the name? What does it convert to? Note, there are spaces between the words and the hyphens.

example:
```
- [My - Header](#my---header)

# My - Header
```

Would that be correct?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17820138/2908724 for terminology on this style. I prefer "kebab-case".

Comment: All those conversions mean that it's a bit of a crap shoot to rely on anything the markdown formatter does to titles and headings. Much better, IMHO to use anchors (as the most upvoted answer recommends), that way links don't break because someone makes a grammar/spelling correction to a title and breaks untold thousands of internal (and external) links.

Comment: @SteventheEasilyAmused indeed — at the cost of polluting a Markdown file with HTML. Depending on the target/audience, this might be a good trade-off... or not. For a simple `README.md` which might be simply read with a non-Markdown viewer, it's best to leave all HTML off — it's less confusing to follow.

Answer (score 53):

The best way to create internal links (related with sections) is create list but instead of link, put `#section` or `#section-title` if the header includes spaces.

**Markdown**

```
Go to section
* [Hello](#hello)  
* [Hello World](#hello-world)
* [Another section](#new-section) <-- it's called 'Another section' in this list but refers to 'New section'


## Hello
### Hello World
## New section
```

**List preview**

```
Go to section
Hello           <-- [Hello](#hello)                 -- go to `Hello` section
Hello World     <-- [Hello World](#hello world)     -- go to `Hello World` section
Another section <-- [Another section](#new-section) -- go to `New section`
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Go to section</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#hello">Hello</a></li>
    <li><a href="#hello-world">Hello World</a></li>
    <li><a href="#new-section">Another section</a> &lt;– it’s called ‘Another section’ in this list but refers to ‘New section’</li>
</ul>
<h2 id="hello">Hello</h2>
<h3 id="hello-world">Hello World</h3>
<h2 id="new-section">New section</h2>
```

It doesn't matter whether it's `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, etc. header, you always refer to it using just one `#`.
All references in section list should be converted to lowercase text as it is shown in the example above.

**The link to the section should be lowercase.** It won't work otherwise. This technique works very well for all Markdown variants, also MultiMarkdown.

Currently I'm using the [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org) to convert documents format. It's much better than MultiMarkdown.
[Test Pandoc here](http://pandoc.org/try/)

Comment: as noted in other comments here. that will not work in any markdown -> html converter that actually follows the standard. Creating anchor tags in headings only happens in SOME converters. Furthemore, they're not going to all convert spaces to dashes. THIS CAN NOT not be counted on.

Comment: I'm using GitHub Markdown in [Atom](https://atom.io/) code editor which has a built-in package named "Markdown Preview". From preview mode I create an html files using context menu "Save as HTML...".

Comment: yes, my point is that you can't count on your technique working anywhere else, and neither the question, nor your answer is specifically about markdown in Atom. The question isn't even about Markdown, it's about MultiMarkdown.

Comment: I'm using this link method but it's not working for me. not sliding to the section/that header.

Comment: Give a heads up to case sensitive. If you define a `## Hello` you should refer to it as `[Whatever you want](#Hello)`

Comment: It works but you have to use **lowercase for link**. `[Section name](#link-to-section)`

Comment: The *Markdown* solution worked for me. I used it inside `VSCode` and with `Typora`.

Answer (score 8):

In mdcharm it is like this:

```
* [Descripción](#descripcion)
* [Funcionamiento](#funcionamiento)
* [Instalación](#instalacion)
* [Configuración](#configuracion)
```

---

```
### Descripción {#descripcion}
### Funcionamiento {#funcionamiento}
### Instalación {#instalacion}
### Configuración {#configuracion}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another option (all the links can be placed at the bottom of the file):

```markdown
Here is an [example label].

  [example label]: #the-anchor-name-or-id "Optional title for mouse hover"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution (derived from [`SaraubhM`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1789493/saurabhm)'s answer)

`**Jump To**: [Hotkeys & Markers](#hotkeys-markers) / [Radii](#radii) / [Route Wizard 2.0](#route-wizard-2-0)`

Which gives you:

**Jump To**: Hotkeys & Markers / Radii / Route Wizard 2.0

Note the changes from  and `.` to `-` and also the loss of the `&` in the links.

Answer (score 0):

An important piece of being able to link to an anchor is *naming* the anchor with an easy-to-use `id`. This is done [with](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#heading-ids) the **`{#foo-bar}`** (extended) syntax on the heading, supported by some processors (Kramdown, Maruku; not Github or SO apparently)

### How To (an *example*) {#how-to}

It's done as shown at the end of this line:

```
### Typical Long Heading (w/ needing _annoying_ "escaping") {#some-heading}
```

This allows for arbitrarily named headings (but keep the IDs simple!), and avoids having to carefully craft them to avoid any escaped characters. It also gives you better control of your document. (Be warned that TOC-generators may not respect these, though.)

Now the *references* can always be made with the simple **`[Important Place](#some-heading)`** syntax, internally; and with `[Some other name maybe](http://example.com/some-page#some-heading)`, externally.

Here (link not even showing up) is a SO processor example showing how it sadly doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

For me, with dataiku, I have a header like that :

```
### Préfixes Redshifts
```

above, if I want jump on it

```
 [Préfixes Redshifts](#pr-fixes-redshifts-1)
```

How I've found "#pr-fixes-redshifts-1" ?
In view mode, the mouse over the destination and wait the tooltip