# Doxygen Markdown Link To Anchor In PDF

Tags: c++, doxygen

Using Doxygen 1.8.6, my mainpage is a Markdown README.md. I'd like to be able to link to anchors within the Markdown file, so I did this:

```
# My Header <a name="my-header"></a>

Check out [my header](#my-header)!
```

This works fine on the HTML documentation, but it does *not* work in the generated PDF. Is there a way to make it work in both places?

Comment: How are you generating PDF, directly from Doxygen or by converting one of the other formats?

Comment: I'm generating latex and running Make on the resulting directory. Is that not the normal way to do this?

Comment: (which uses pdflatex, by the way).

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the option
`PDF_HYPERLINKS         = YES`
in your doxygen.config ?

Comment: Yes, I have that option enabled.

Comment: Did you try without the "-" in your anchor-name ?

you can maybe find more info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695439/how-do-you-create-link-to-a-named-anchor-in-multimarkdown)

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work either. The link you referenced is what I used to try this in the first place. Unfortunately, it does not seem to work in Doxygen.

Comment: Well... Doxygen's PDF generation, anyway.