# adding local references in markdown

Tags: markdown

how to add local references in markdown language? for example i need the following code in rst to be converted in to the markdown.

```
Admin Operations
----------------
.. note:: You need to create an admin session in order to perform admin operations.

- :java:ref:`Create Account <com.xxx.yyy.client.Admin.createAccount(String, String, String, String, String)>`

  You can create end users for an admin/paid account.

  ::

    Profile profile = adminSession.getAdmin().createAccount(username, password, email, firstName, lastName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for, but I *am* pretty sure that Markdown doesn't do it natively. Markdown is [very simple](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> The idea for Markdown is to make it easy to read, write, and edit prose.

It deliberately lacks many features found in other markup languages, including any kind of cross-referencing.

Depending on exactly what your needs are, you may be able to use inline HTML to achieve them:

> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself. There’s no need to preface it or delimit it to indicate that you’re switching from Markdown to HTML; you just use the tags.

See also: [How to link to a named anchor in Multimarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6695439/354577)