# How to give bookmark links in Jupyter Notebook that work on GitHub?

Tags: python, html, github, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a [project](https://github.com/JuzerShakir/Investigate_TMDb_Movies) where I have a Jupyter notebook file named `'Investigating_Database.ipynb'`. As you open this file on GitHub you see a `'Table of Contents'` section at the top followed by links which refer inside that notebook file, but as you click on those links, it doesn't work. I have tried to give links both in HTML5 and Markdown but none of it works. But the links work fine on Jupyter Notebook.

I have searched and tried many different syntaxes but none work.

Has anyone encountered this problem before and debugged it successfully or it's just a bug or not supported by GitHub?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132862/html-anchors-in-a-jupyter-notebook-on-github

Comment: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/JuzerShakir/Investigate_TMDb_Movies/blob/master/Investigating_Database.ipynb