# Link to an arbitrary spot in a multimarkdown file

Tags: multimarkdown

I'm trying to make the following work:

```
Here is my markdown text I would like to link to. [link]

Then I write something else.

Then I say [see above](link)
```

This does not work and I cannot find a way to link to some arbitrary text.

Note: This is not a duplicate of [6695493](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695439/how-to-link-to-a-named-anchor-in-multimarkdown/6706594) as that is a conversation about headers.

This is *not* a duplicate of any answer that talks about linking to headers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link to part of the same document in Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822089/how-to-link-to-part-of-the-same-document-in-markdown)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is, ["No you cannot do this with pure markdown"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2822864/4360746)

You can [put some HTML into your file to create a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6494918/4360746) and then link to that.