# Markdown Anchor Link With Same Name But Different Sections

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

You can link to an anchor heading in markdown quite easily.
`[link to anchor heading](#background)`

Plenty of stackoverflow questions deal with it such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695439/how-to-link-to-a-named-anchor-in-multimarkdown) or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822089/how-to-link-to-part-of-the-same-document-in-markdown).

But I cannot seem to find a way to link to anchors that share the same name but are in different sections.

So for example, I cannot link to the background section in a different section.
`[link to database background](#database#background)`

As opposed to say :
`[link to front end background](#front-end#background)`

This does not work either.
`[link to database background](#database##background)`

I would expect the markdown anchor link to follow the section path specified.  Is this not possible?  Or am I using the wrong syntax?

Comment: [The original Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) doesn't create header anchors at all. What processor are you using? We'll have to know that if we can help.

Comment: I am generally editing markdown via visual studio code.

Comment: I am flexible though if you know of any processor that treats markdown sections the way I suggest.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no markdown specification that I know of that supports specifying a *section-subsection-...* format. As I understand it, they're converted to something like `<a name=header>header</a>` links, and there's no info on what the parent header is.

A workaround that I use is that when a header name is repeated, it gets a `-1` appended to it so you can access with `#header-1`. The same pattern is applied for the next copy (`#header-2`), and the next (`#header-3`) and so forth.

Here is a sample markdown (working on VS Code 1.38.1):

```
# App

[module 1 background](#background)

[module 2 background](#background-1)

[module 3 background](#background-2)

## Module 1

### background

## Module 2

### SubModule 2-1

#### SubSubModule 2-1-1

##### background

## Module 3

### background
```

The problem with this workaround is that you'll have to keep track of the order of the duplicate names, which gets quite tedious if you have a lot. The good thing is it's easier to create a link to a duplicate name embedded in a series of headers (`#background-1` is easier than `##module2###submodule-2-1####subsubmodule-2-1-1#####background`).

I don't know exactly how or why this is, but VS Code is using the [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/) specification and the [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) library to parse it, as mentioned in [Markdown editing](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#_does-vs-code-support-github-flavored-markdown) doc.

Comment: Thanks Gino. This indeed works.  Unfortunately, it is not sustainable if you edit the document. If you add a background section somewhere in between your first and last mention, you have to edit all the links again.  Not sure why they did not do a simple path syntax which is intuitive enough while being sustainable. In the absence of any other viable alternative, I will select yours as the answer.

Answer (score 10):

As stated in the [Markdown Guide](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#html), some applications allow you to use HTML tags in Markdown-formatted text (e.g. [GitHub](https://github.github.com/gfm/#raw-html)). Check your Markdown application's documentation to be sure.

If HTML is allowed, you can use the following:

```markdown
# Front end

- [Background](#front-end-background)

<h2 id="front-end-background">Background</h2>

# Database

- [Background](#database-background)

<h2 id="database-background">Background</h2>
```

In the example above, `<h2>` is the same as `##`. It also works with other headings.

Answer (score 0):

- painfully, github's markdown/rst/asciidoc do not allow to give a header a custom anchor id/link
- but you want to have a very large document, but avoid header names collision
- an approach/solution using hash superscript

  - https://github.com/sergeiudris/lab.gtihub-markdown-big-doc-header-name-uniqueness-dilemma-2020-09-05

Answer (score 0):

Just a note - but it doesn't solve the problem here of identical header links that are then re-ordered.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70699884/836330 which does make adding header links pretty easy.  Identical links show up like this in the Suggestions:

[image: identical markdown header links]

But there should be an issue filed to show parent headers in the suggestions (at least as additional info, Ctrl+Space) for identical headers.  But there is no automatic reordering of the links or enough info, other than `-1`, `-2`, etc. for knowing where those identical headers are located in the files.