# How to link to a bullet point within a section in markdown

Tags: github, markdown, readme

I am making a readme file for my GitHub project and need to link to a specific bullet point within a specific section in the readme file.  Is this possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695439/how-to-link-to-a-named-anchor-in-multimarkdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly in Markdown, but you can use an HTML list and add an `id` to whatever item you want to link to:

```markdown
<ul>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li id="bar">Bar</li>
</ul>
```

Then, you can link to it using that `id`, e.g.

```markdown
[Link to Bar](#bar)

<a href="#bar">Link to Bar</a>
```

Or from another document:

```markdown
[Link to Bar](https://github.com/bj97301/project/blob/main/README.md#bar)
```

Comment: So no way to do it without the id?  I get yelled at for using html .

Comment: No, there is no way to do it with just plain Markdown. I suggest you tell whoever "yells at you" for doing this that [inline HTML has been part of Markdown's architecture from the very beginning](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html). If you don't want to use it, fine, but that does restrict what you can do.

Comment: Good point. I’ll look into it.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it the following way

```
    * [Main Link:]
(https://github.com/MazinIsmail/JavaLearnings/tree/master/src/main/concurrency/com/atomic/learnings)
```

Main Link:

Sub Link:

To add subpoints, add two spaces before the asterisk symbol.